# How to map an array of objects by a given field?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects:

```js
let tempArray = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 13
  }
  ...
]
```

How can I create a new array that would contain only `name` fields from all objects of the `tempArray` array?

Comment: Already found the dupe @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @CodeManiac - Gah, apologies for the assumption.

Comment: Yeah, I was too quick clicking :-) @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @chrispbacon - I've **never** done that. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Trying using `map()`

```js
let tempArray = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Tom',
        age: 11
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Jerry',
        age: 13
    }
]

const res = tempArray.map(i => i.name)
console.log(res)
```